# How to tell if game is running in fullscreen and borderless window

Tags: pc, windows

If I have a particular game that is taking up my entire screen, what ways are there to figure out whether that game is running in Fullscreen or Borderless Windowed mode?

The obvious solution for most games is to check what the graphics options say. One problem I've seen with this advice though is that I've heard of some games (can't think of any specific examples) where it's "Fullscreen" option actually runs the game in a Borderless Window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> out of the game and the game minimizes, then its fullscreen (requires another application window in the background). If it stays open, then its borderless window.

To add to the paragraph above: If you don't have any other application window in the background, then simply open the taskmanager via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> and see if the game minimizes (another option is <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the `Run` window).

Also if you have a second monitor, you will only be able to access it without <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> when the game is in borderless window. While the game is in fullscreen your mouse is locked to that specific screen.

Another option which I am currently not entirely sure about is the <kbd>WIN</kbd> key. If you hit it, the start menu opens up and should minimize fullscreen games, while borderless window games stay open

Comment: A few things to note: Some fullscreen games may not minimize if you don't have another window open in the background. Also, some games (especially strategy ones) can keep your mouse locked to their window.

Comment: @Nolonar <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> requires another application running in the background that is true. Though I can't remember ever having played a game that locked the mouse to 1 screen in borderless window mode

Comment: You don't normally need another window open for ALT-TAB to work. If you do it's because the game tried to implement it's own handling of ALT-TAB rather than relying on DirectX's default behaviour which will minimize the fullscreen application if there's no other application to switch to.

Comment: @RossRidge just tested on Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice, and this game requires another application window to ALT+TAB out of it

Comment: I tested it on HOMM5 and it didn't need another window.  A lot of newer games are borderless window though.

Comment: Though thinking about it, it might be a DirectX 9 (or earlier) versus DirectX 10 (or later) thing.  It's been a long time since I didn't have a bunch of other windows open while playing games.